# Simulate MongoDB replicaset on Openshift

Tags: mongodb, openshift-origin

I am currently working on a project and I am using openshift as paas.
Basically it fit to all my needs. I have my website, my statics and my api webserver.

Only my api webserver is calling my DB

Now coming a question with my database. I am using mongodb.
The problem is that currently replicaset in openshift is technology preview and should not be used in production because it is using ephemeral storage. So if all the nodes are falling, all the data are lost.

We cannot scale as well the mongodb pod because it could result in multiple write action and create real issues.

So I had an idea but I would like to know if you see something wrong.

As a recapitulative a replicaset is composed of:
One primary => this is the only one which is allowed to make write actions
Multiple secondaries => ensure read actions
Arbitrary => for the moment I don't focus on it.

So my idea to simulate a replicaset (it needs some tweeks on my side):
- Create an instance of mongodb which will be rooted by primary.db.example.com
- Create an instance of mongodb which will be rooted by secondary.db.example.com

Both will point to the same persistent storage.

Then in my api:

- Reference primary.db.example.com and secondary.db.example.com and call them accordingly:

  - If I make a write operation I am calling: primary.db.example.com
  - If I make a read operation I am calling secondary.db.example.com

In this way I would be able to scale secondaries for read operation.
And if primary is falling down Openshift will try to recreate the pod (like when there is an election for new primary)

I know that it is not the best solution but this is currently the only solution I found (except creating an external replica, which imply lot of questions about security, cost etc)

What do you think about this temporary solution (to wait a real production ready Openshift solution)

Regards

Comment: I have to think about it. But one thing I noticed: Thinking of one node being primary and others being secondary sure as hell will get you into problems. You have an uneven number of non-delayed, non-hidden nodes, one of which happens to be elected primary. Please also note that you only need an arbiter when you have an even number of voting members.

Comment: I would not recommend you to simulate a MongoDB replica set in this manner. A replica set was designed to perform High Availability functions automatically, and from the outside, looks like a single-server deployment. That is, drivers will reconnect as necessary, and the only thing the application needs to care about is how durable do you want your writes to be (using write concerns). Could you please edit your question explaining what your goal is and why the need to simulate a replica set?